# Compiler options in Visual Studio 2015 for VB applications

Tags: visual-studio

I am used to using the gcc compiler from the command line and adding flags such as -o to create object code and -S to stop the compiler mid way to produce assembler code.

I have found by trial and error that visual studio 2015 produces a lot of files for a console project after clicking the run button , one of which is an executable file which is the machine code, I think.

It all seems a little out of my control.

**Problem:** How do I issue compiler directives through Visual Studio 2015 Visual Basic.net compiler so that I can produce assembler code instead of machine code then inspect the file from within my project?

Comment: .Net compilers produce IL, not machine code or assembler.  Use ildasm or ILSpy.

Comment: Thy [this setup](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18784) and let me know whether it gives you insight you expect.